# Get input value without the prompt

Tags: python

```
def get_text_filename():
    '''() -> str

       Return the name of the file containing the plaintext or cipher text.
    '''

    return input("Enter the file to read: ")
```

After the filename is inputted the first time, I want to be able to call on what it was that the filename inputted was. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result to a variable:

```
filename = get_text_filename()
print filename
```

Then you can get the string that the user enters using this `filename` variable.

Comment: Where would I put that? Outside or inside the function?

Comment: Outside the function.

Comment: If I put it outside the function, it says get_text_filename() is not defined

Comment: Did you define `get_text_filename` in the same python file?